# HTML5 Websocket TCP Port Listening

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, tcp

I am integration a desktop application with my asp.net mvc app. Desktop application is publishing the data on port:10000 which i need to listen in browser. Below is the code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         function WebSocketTest() {
            
            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
               alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
               
               // Let us open a web socket
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:10000");
                
               ws.onopen = function() {
                  
                  // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                  ws.send("Message to send");
                  alert("Message is sent...");
               };
                
               ws.onmessage = function (evt) { 
                  var received_msg = evt.data;
                  alert("Message is received...");
               };
                
               ws.onclose = function() { 
                  
                  // websocket is closed.
                  alert("Connection is closed..."); 
               };
            } else {
              
               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
         }
      </script>
        
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <div id = "sse">
         <a href = "javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
      </div>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

The issue I am facing is when desktop app publish the data on port, connection terminates and i am getting a message connection closed. any help?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code i dont see anywhere where you close the conecction with ws, so i think its the server who closes the connection after sending you the message.